# Flutter | How to apply fontFamily from ThemeData to AppBar & FABs

Tags: flutter

I can't figure a way to apply the fontFamily from ThemeData to the appBar & FAB.

How to achieve that given that I don't want to apply it on widgets individually?

Here is the ThemeData initialization

```
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.apply(
            fontFamily: 'MaShanZheng',
        ),
      ),
```

And here is the result

[image]

Comment: Make separate Utilities file and use as common widget `title` inside `AppBar` widget

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing right now but I'm wondering if there is another way using ThemeData

Comment: As per my opinion, I haven't found any other approach using `ThemeData` so I used the above one.

Answer (score 4):

This is how you would do it for the `AppBar`.

```
MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
              textTheme: TextTheme(title: ,button: ),
              appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
                  textTheme: TextTheme(
                      title: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily://your font family
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontStyle: FontStyle.italic)))),
          home:Home(),
        );
```

For the FAB, the `textTheme` is decided by the `button` parameter of the  `accentTextTheme` parameter in the `ThemeData` widget.

ie.

```
return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        accentTextTheme:TextTheme(button:TextStyle(fontSize:63),),
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
```

Comment: This is partially correct, I could apply the font to the appBar as mentioned. The FAB part didn't work.

Comment: Did you experiment with both of the `title` and `button` parameters?

Comment: Yes I did add both parameters :(

Comment: I have edited my answer.  It should definitely work now.

Comment: `textTheme`  in `AppBarTheme` is deprecated in version 3 so this does not seem to work anymore

Answer (score 1):

In version 3 of flutter the use of `textTheme` seems to be deprecated inside `appBarTheme` so I made it work like this:

```dart
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

MaterialApp(
  ...      
  theme: ThemeData(
  colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(
    primarySwatch: Colors.green,
  ).copyWith(
    secondary: Colors.orange,
  ),
  appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
    titleTextStyle: GoogleFonts.changa(
      fontSize: 34,
    ),
    ),
  ),
);
```